# Huge KDE title bars after installing kubuntu-desktop

Tags: 16.04, kde

I'm currently running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I decided to try out KDE Plasma after using it in a VM and being pretty happy with it. Unfortunately, when I switch over in my main Ubuntu installation, through running `apt install kubuntu-desktop`, I end up with really tall and goofy looking window titlebars:

[image: KDE 5.7 with large title bars]

**Update** Also - window titles themselves are odd. Configuring settings for the breeze theme sets the title to "org.kde.breeze - SystemSettings"

Comment: Is it in KDE plasma session or in Unity session?

Comment: This is in KDE plasma after a reboot of the system and logging into Plasma - no unity involved.